# How to write a query in SQLite for Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on Android SQLite databses and my requirement is to get the data from two tables. The tables are status and diners.

Status Table:

[image]

Diners Table:

[image]

My intention is to get the data of color_desc from status table when the din-status_color column value from diners table and color_status-id column value from status table are equal.

How to write the query in Android SQLite?

Comment: What have you done? Show us some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an full tutorial it is help in the bast i hope help u too.

[Good tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

and this one for [beginners](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-sqlite-database-example)

Answer (score 0):

First iterate over the diners table and get all values from column "din_status_color" ( maybe all greater than 0)

After that iterate over the status table and compare the "color_status-id" with the "din_status_color" from the diners table. If it matches return the color_desc.

This will help you:

```
protected String getColorDesc(){
    String[] din_status_color = {"din-status_color"};
    String[] color_desc = {"color_desc"};

    Cursor cursor = database.query("diners", din_status_color, "din_status_color > '0'", null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Cursor cursor2 = database.query("status", color_desc, "color_status-id = '" + cursor.getInt(0) + "'", null, null, null, null);
    cursor2.moveToFirst();

    String colorDesc = cursor2.getString(0);

    cursor2.close();
    cursor.close();

    return colorDesc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SQLite expert, but I think a simple join statement should work. Something like this might get you started.

```
  Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select diners.id, status.color_desc from dinners inner join status on status.color_status_id = diners.din_status_color");
```

In this example the cursor would have the dinner id and the color_desc